# Decimal value from bit group in word math explanation

Tags: math, rgb, bit, 16-bit

```
11111 111111 11111  > 16 bit
  R      G     B
```

how can I get the R/G/B values?

```
R = x/2048 (2048 are the 6+5 G+B  11 bit)
G = x-R*2048/32 (32 are the B )
```

is there a simple explanation of this? why should the decimal value be divided by others bit to get the single group value?

Comment: You can see it as masks and shifts

Comment: Mind your Operator Precedence: your `G` calculation is wrong in about every programming language I know (.. except Postscript, but that's only because it is a postfix language, so you could not have made the same mistake with that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get R you have to move 11 bits on the right so that G and B disappear. So

`R=x>>11`

but every shift of 1 bit is equivalent to a division by 2 so the expression above is equivalent to

```
R=X/(2^11)=x/2048
```

And so you get the R.

To get the G, according to the formula, you can first remove the R, which is the R you obtained previously but shift back of 11 bits (or multiplied by 2048). Now done this you have a number like:

```
111111 11111
```

You shift left of 5 bits (or divide for 32) and you get the result.

Note that in practice you can do this easier doing this:

```
B=(x and 0x1F)
G=((x>>5) and 0x3F)
R=((x>>11) and 0x1F)
```

Comment: Better make that last one `and 0x3F` as well -- you don't know where it has been.